# How to iterate through text and replace certain words with a dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create something that searches through a sentence and takes whatever words you want out and switches them with a replacement. Here's what I have so far but it just returns none instead of the sentence

```
def testing ():
    test_dic = {'dog' : 'Censored'}
    text = raw_input('Input your sentence here: ').lower()
    text = text.join(" ")

    for words in text:
        if words in test_dic:
            for i, j in test_dic.iteritems():
                clean_text = text.replace(i, j)
            return clean_text
```

I'm new to python so that might explain if I'm trying to do it in a wrong or non-pythonic way. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please, Can you mention a sample Input and sample Output case.

Comment: I think you wanted to use `split` instead of `join` on line 4

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with list comprehension:

```
def testing ():
   test_dic = {'dog' : 'Censored'}
   text = raw_input('Input your sentence here: ').lower()

   return ' '.join([test_dic.get(word, word) for word in text.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `join` where you probably meant `split`. You also have an extraneous loop through the dictionary. The following code will iterate through each word and either keep it or replace it depending on whether it is present as a key in the dictionary.

```
def testing ():
    test_dic = {'dog' : 'Censored'}
    text = raw_input('Input your sentence here: ').lower()
    text = text.split(" ")

    new_text = []
    for word in text:
        if word in test_dic:
            new_text.append(test_dic[word])
        else:
            new_text.append(word)
    return " ".join(new_text)

print testing()
```